# How to real time convert Ethernet packet to Wireless packet?

Tags: windows, wireless, ethernet, wifi

In case of Ethernet header we will have destination Mac address and Source Mac Address.

In case of 802.11 packets there is at minimum three Mac addresses and in some cases 4 Mac addresses.

How is 802.11 packet formed using 802.3 packet? I know that native wifi is doing conversion in case windows. I want to know how it is achieving?

Comment: I'm not sure that Windows creates an 802.3 packet (containing the IP packet) and then converts that to an 802.11 packet.  It might just create an 802.11 packet (containing the IP packet) directly.

Answer (score 1):

"How is 802.11 packet formed using 802.3 packet?"

The conversion (between 802.3 and 802.11 MAC frames) happens at link layer. The implementation details are platform and driver-dependent.

An example of how these are done in Linux kernel (using soft-MAC 802.11 driver):

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/wireless/util.c#L412

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/wireless/util.c#L530